# Sobre compilación en .Net

Tags: .net, cil

Cuando creo un paquete de distribución en .NET se generan assemblies (CIL), quisiera saber si en adelante ¿la compilación a lenguaje intermedio será un proceso repetitivo o únicamente los assemblies será convertidos a codigo nativo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No termino de entender tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

CIL es el lenguaje intermedio sobre el que se compilan los fuentes de .NET (C#, VB, F#...)

Cuando se compila desde Visual Studio, se compilan a lenguaje intermedio todos los ensamblados que se hayan modificado. Es decir, no se recompilan los ensamblados que tengas en tu solución si no has tocado su código fuente.

El CIL en ejecución, se "interpreta" aunque hay un proceso de optimización interno que va creando código nativo. Este proceso lo realiza el JIT internamente.

En cuanto a código nativo puro, se puede compilar el CIL en el código nativo de la máquina en la que desees ejecutar (Windows o Linux, por ejemplo) pero es un proceso posterior y que yo sepa se recompilan todos los ensamblados.

Puedes consultar por ejemplo este documento sobre .Net Native: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/net-native/

Answer (score 0):

la conversión a lenguaje intermedio (MSIL) la realiza el programador al compilar el lenguaje de alto nivel (c#, vb). La conversión del MSIL a codigo nativo lo realiza el JIT cada vez que el usuario ejecute la aplicación.